# NavigationLinkSet can't be reach from LWC component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, compile-error, digital-experience

When I am using NavigationLinkSet object in my apex class, and importing any other method from that class in my LWC component - I've got an error:

'Error:(1, 1) FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - Invalid type: NavigationLinkSet: Source'

The org is in Spring'22 release. Every component is in 54.0 api version.
Everything is for Digital Experience (community) purposes. Custom template.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that Digital Experience is actually enabled in the org you're trying to deploy to?

Comment: Yes, everything is already deployed. Honestly, I am working on Digital Experience for months, so the project is almost ready to go live. I've just found dirty workaround. Commented out every occurrence of NavigationLinkSet in imported apex class, deploy LWC code, rollback apex changes. 
That's really strange it happened only to me, and it has no influence for whole app - only that compilation error.

Comment: I've had the same error. For me it turned out I need to deploy the whole lwc bundle instead of just JS which turned out my IDE was doing by default. I'm using Illuminated Cloud.